# Split array and create a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array of messages between two users, like a private chat. User A can have 2-3 chats going on with users B, C, and D.

Now I have to split this array and obtain an array of length 3 (messages between A-B, A-C, A-D). To do this I use this code:

```
var gloabal = [];
var myArray = [];      
function splitArray () {

    alert("Split");

    var oldArray = myArray;
    var newArray = [];

    var object = oldArray[0];
    var daUtente = object.get("daUtente");
    var aUtente = object.get("aUtente");            

    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        var obj = myArray[i];
        var newDaUtente = obj.get("daUtente");
        var newaUtente = obj.get("aUtente");

        if ((newDaUtente == daUtente) && (newaUtente == aUtente) || 
            (newDaUtente == aUtente) && (newaUtente == daUtente)) {
                newArray.push(obj);
                oldArray.splice(i, 1);
        }

        var lastObj = myArray[myArray.length - 1];

        if (obj == lastObj){
            gloabal.push(newArray);
            newArray = [];

            if(oldArray.length != 0) {
                myArray = oldArray;
                splitArray ();
            }
            else {
                myArray = gloabal;
                alert("end");       
            }   
        }       
    }
}
```

This logic works with an iPhone application, but with Javascript I have some problem. I think that the cause is my bad knowledge of Javascript. Can you help me fix the mistake? I think that the problem is in:

```
else {
    myArray = gloabal;
    alert("end");       
}
```

because I don't see "end" alert!

Example:
array:

```
1 - user A - user B - message
2 - user B - user A - message
3 - user A - user B - message
4 - user A - user B - message
5 - user A - user C - message
6 - user C - user A - message
7 - user A - user D - message
```

I want this:
array 1

```
1 - user A - user B - message
2 - user B - user A - message
3 - user A - user B - message
4 - user A - user B - message
```

array 2

```
1 - user A - user C - message
2 - user C - user A - message
```

array 3

```
1 - user A - user D - message
```

newArray = [array 1,array 2,array 3]

Comment: Please show us some example input and the expected output. It's not clear what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: I edit my question with an example!

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly those arrays contain. Could you please make it an *executable* example? Try to log the value of `JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 4)`, you can post that as a array literal. Btw, what's the result of your function, it doesn't `return` anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your code, but here is how I'd construct such a thing.

First, I have a simple function called `getId`:

```
function getId(to, from) {                                                                                                                                                                    
    // we use sort so that we get a consistent id; results in alphabetic sorting                                                                                                              
    return [to, from].sort().join("-");                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

This function constructs an identifier which is unique for every conversation pairing assuming your usernames are unique. Further, this id is the same for both `A->B` and `B->A` because it sorts the `to` and `from` values alphabetically.

This function is used to populate an `Object` with the message values. Here is my implementation of `splitArray`:

```
function splitArray() {
    var intermediary = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var id = getId(data[i].to, data[i].from);
        if(intermediary.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            intermediary[id].push(data[i]);
        } else {
            intermediary[id] = [data[i]];
        }
    }
    // xform from object to array
    result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(intermediary);
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        result.push(intermediary[keys[i]]);
    }
}
```

I have my data laid out like this:

```
var data = [                                                                                                                                                                                  
    {'to': "B", 'from': "A", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "A", 'from': "B", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "B", 'from': "A", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "B", 'from': "A", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "C", 'from': "A", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "A", 'from': "C", 'msg': "message"},                                                                                                                                               
    {'to': "D", 'from': "A", 'msg': "message"}                                                                                                                                                
];
```

Provided that the fields `to` and `from` exist, the function will work (and those fields could easily be renamed in `splitArray`).

The function works by constructing a mapping of user pairs to messages, then flattens this into a 2D array. An intermediary `Object` is used because even though flattening creates a small processing overhead at the end of the function, it is faster than repeatedly searching for user pairs in order to enter them into the appropriate array. Here is the result structure that I get from this:

```
[
    [
        {"to":"B","from":"A","msg":"message"},
        {"to":"A","from":"B","msg":"message"},
        {"to":"B","from":"A","msg":"message"},
        {"to":"B","from":"A","msg":"message"}
    ],
    [
        {"to":"C","from":"A","msg":"message"},
        {"to":"A","from":"C","msg":"message"}
    ],
    [
        {"to":"D","from":"A","msg":"message"}
    ]
]
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: I used global variables because that is what you used, however I would **STRONGLY** recommend using a parameterized function which returns a value such as:

```
function splitArray(messages) {
    .....
    return results;
}
```

Global variables and functions are easy to write, but hard to maintain.